# VS2017 show error: Dictionary is not a collection

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2017, resharper

I have a class in C# with a Dictionary

```
public class Testing {
   public Dictionary<string, OtherClass> AdditionalProperties {get;} = new Dictionary<string, ISomeIFace>();
}

public class OtherClass : ISomeIFace {
    public string SomeProp { get; set; }
}
```

which is used in a XAML file

```
<CheckBox Grid.Column="0" IsChecked="{Binding AdditionalProperties[SomeKey].(local:OtherClass.SomeProp)}" />
```

It shows the following error:

> Type 'Dictionary' is not a collection.

with the curly line under `SomeKey`.

I installed Resharper shortly and I have the suspicion that it did not show me this error before.

I'm still able to compile and the code runs successfully but it would be nicer if there were no false errors.

Comment: What are `AdditionalProperties`, `SomeKey`, and `OtherClass.SomeProp`?

Comment: @FurkanKambay Sorry. Added the informaiton.

Comment: I'm not sure why it says that but I would try putting `Path=` after `Binding`. Also you should move that logic to the ViewModel anyway.

Comment: It is all ViewModel I have not named the classes in the example with ViewModel.

Comment: @FurkanKambay Adding `Path=` did not help.

Comment: I meant, create a property in the ViewModel like this:  that returns `AdditionalProperties["SomeKey"].SomeProp` and then in your XAML, bind to that property.That's the way it should be.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164772/discussion-between-furkan-kambay-and-redx).

Answer (score 1):

Specifying the attribute as a nested element seems to fix the error.
Try to convert this:

```
<CheckBox Grid.Column="0" IsChecked="{Binding AdditionalProperties[SomeKey].(local:OtherClass.SomeProp)}" />
```

to this:

```
<CheckBox Grid.Column="0">
    <CheckBox.IsChecked>
        <Binding Path="AdditionalProperties[SomeKey].(local:OtherClass.SomeProp)" />
    </CheckBox.IsChecked>
</CheckBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

From Resharper standpoint:

**If it's a matter of a Resharper 'error' warning**, then notice you can do the following by doing Ctrl+Enter on it:

1. Configure the inspection severity (so that it shows as a hint, not as an error)
2. Check 'Why is Resharper suggesting this', which takes you to a page explaining potential issue with your code

[image]

Please notice, this answer does not evaluate whether your binding, viewmodel  etc is properly designed - its just a matter of dealing with, as you put it *'would be nicer if there were no false errors.'*

Answer (score 0):

Let's say I have a MenuItem. Set the dictionary to the DataContext of the MenuItem. Then set the key value in the parameter, for example Command

```
<MenuItem Header="Exit" DataContext="{Binding MenuCommands, Mode=OneTime}"
        Command="{Binding [File_Exit], Mode=OneTime}" />
```